# Visual Flow screen with data type conflict between text and picklist

Tags: visual-workflow, data-types

I created a flow where I reference a picklist field in a screen. The field in the screen "Tipo_de_Contrato2" is Choice Type "Dropdown list" and Value Data Type "Text".

[image: Screen Field Tipo_de_Contrato2]

I associated a choice, "Tipo", which Value Data Type is "Picklist".

[image: Picklist Choice]

I use the stored value later for several decision and to determine a variable in my sObject.

When I want to deploy this flow, I get an error message:

> Tipo_de_Contrato2 (Screen Field) - The data type of choice lookup "Tipo" > doesn't match the data type of its parent screen field.

That doesn't make sense to me as text is my only viable option for data value type.

Is there anywhere I have to say a "ISPICKLIST" kind of thing in order to get picklist to be recognized as text?

Comment: I did find a workaround by recreating the choice options from the picklist fields as three single choices with the 'stored value' as text. That worked for the deploy, however I do not find that the optimal solution as any changes in the picklist field will not be automatically reflected in the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that picklist fields like this are not yet in your Production environment.  That was a new feature in Winter '16.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_picklist.htm

Comment: David, thank you, you are absolutely right. I was just faster using the new features than the release.